# How to track reboots in Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, reboot, crashes

Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Verizon) with Android 4.1.1 (unrooted).

I seem to be having unusually frequent reboots of my phone; sometimes multiple times in a day. Certainly much more frequent than with Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.4).

Additionally, my battery life seems to be lower since the upgrade from 4.0.4. (It might be my imagination, but it might be running hotter than I remember, too.)

I've been looking for some common denominator but I'm baffled.

What can I do to try to find out what is causing these crashes?

(No suggestions that require rooting, please.)

Comment: Did you consider any of the monitoring tools available on the playstore, like e.g. [SystemPanel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1) or [System Tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.pmw)? They constantly monitor your device, so you could check the collected data even after a reboot. Though they might not be able to collect the required logcat data, the collected information might prove useful.

Comment: @Izzy: I'll have a look at those.

Comment: I played around with them a while ago. From SystemPanel you would need the paid version for recording (the free version only permits live-view). SystemTuner might be your first choice: *Record (optionally at boot) activities in the background [...] Display log(cat) for all/one process (even on JellyBean Android 4.1)* -- and that's for the (linked) free version. // Crossing fingers -- keep us updated, so I might convert it to an answer if it's worth it :)

Comment: Another thing worth investigating, look in `/proc/last_kmsg`, that's the last kernel log prior to reboot...

Answer (score 1):

[System Tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.pmw) looks like it could help you figure out what's going on. Excerpts from the app's description:

> - Display log(cat) for all/one process (even on JellyBean Android 4.1)
> - Record (optionally at boot) activities in the background
> - Record all apps or all processes
> - Allows analyzing past recordings without limits

I didn't try it for this special purpose, but the description suggests you can check what was going on when the device went down even afterwards: which processes were running, memory and CPU status, and more. As it is able to read system logs fine even on JellyBean, it should be able to give you the information needed to figure out what is going on.